# XPath for link in an html page by using the label of the link

Tags: html, xpath

I have a link that can not be identified in my html page shown below:

```
<a href="/somthing/confirm_delete_somthing?&id=12">Delete this monitor</a>
```

What is the XPath to identify the link by the label `Delete this monitor`?

something like `//a[@label="Delete this monitor"]`?

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for a better solution than the currently accepted one. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `@label` with `text()` which represents a text value of a node.

`//a[text()="Delete this monitor"]`

For cases where the text is on another line, such as

```
<a>
   Delete this monitor
</a>
```

you can use `normalize-space()` function which removes starting and trailing spaces:

`//a[normalize-space(text())="Delete this monitor"]`

Answer (score 2):

**Use**:

```
//a[. = "Delete this monitor"]
```

or

```
//a[normalize-space() ="Delete this monitor"]
```

**This will select the node even when it is something like the following**:

```
<a href="/somthing/confirm_delete_somthing?&id=12">Delete <strong>this</strong> monitor</a>
```

**In contrast, the expression from currently accepted answer *does not* select such a node**.

Comment: lets say i didnt know the end of node, i.e i know its going to start with "Delete this"  but was not sure what the third word is, what do i use then? or would the 'normalize-space()' work?

Comment: @Mo: Use: `starts-with(normalize-space(), 'Delete this')`